# Twisted generating new clients for reactor

Tags: python, client, twisted

Generally in Twisted (Python), you define some listeners or connections or looping operations and add them to the reactor and then call reactor.run(). Is there any way to add new connections from within other event loops? Say I want to have a server, and then this server spawns other clients, each having their own on data receive scope.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create as many client connections as you'd like to a particular server.  Disregarding code quality/design patterns, client connections can be made anywhere within your code.

```
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor

class SomeProtocol(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self):
        # This is what I believe you're asking about
        for x in range(5):
            reactor.connectTCP('localhost', 8000, SomeClientFactory())

class SomeServerFactory(protocol.Factory):
    def buildProtocol(self):
        return SomeProtocol()

reactor.listenTCP(8000, SomeServerFactory())
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Perfect, is there a design reason why multiple client connections is a bad design? The connections would be to different servers not the same one, how else would be a better way to do this?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with creating multiple clients and making multiple asynchronous requests with twisted (it's one of the main use cases for the package).